# Toggle element in page when clicking a hash link

Tags: jquery, html, css, anchor

I have some jQuery that converts a definition list into an expandable/collapsible list of FAQs.

```
// Toggle expand/collapse
$('.faq a').click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle('fast');
});

var hash = document.URL.substr(document.URL.indexOf('#'));
$(hash).addClass('active').next().show();
$(hash).parent().parent().prev('a').addClass('active').next().show();
```

I have several links to FAQs throughout the site and clicking on them sends you to the FAQ page and expands the relevant question, the problem is that some of the FAQ answers have links to other questions and while the hash link jumps to the relevant question it doesn't expand the answer.

Is this because the jQuery is in an $(document).ready(function() so the code only activates after the page is reloaded? Do I need to trigger a reload?

CHeers

[See my jsFiddle for full code.](http://jsfiddle.net/stefwill/KAQBP/)

Comment: I think, apart from anything else, you've got invalid HTML: the only valid child-elements of a `dl` are `dt` and `dd`; you've got `a` elements in there as well. Which Chrome's Inspector seems happy to allow, but according to a (quick) reading of the spec seems to be wrong. (Ref: [Crouping content: the `dl` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element).

Comment: You can use (a) `window.location.hash.substr(1)` to get the hash, and (b) `window.onhashchange` to monitor hash changes (instead of your click event).

Comment: @DavidThomas the reason for the change is for accessibility. The links need to be keyboard accessible and a `dt` isn't.

Comment: It's still invalid, though. Which means it'll potentially be unpredictably altered by browsers constructing their DOM. Either nest the `a` within a `dt` (or `dd`), or *use* a `dt` with a tabindex attribute set (which should allow for keyboard navigation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
//for the demo in fiddle you need to use the selector ul li a
$('.faq dd a[href^="#"]').click(function(){
    $($(this).attr('href')).trigger('click')
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/J6zQt/)

Comment: Yeah as you state in your fiddle,

`$('.faq dd a[href^="#"], ul li a')`

Works a treat.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking a hash link doesn't reload the page, it just navigates within the page.

You can bind a click event to the hash links that does the work for you. for example:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
   $($(this).attr('href')).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle('fast');
});
```